# Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 730 (ADL-S GT1) Second Display. Detects at boot, shoows splash, disappears at desktop

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors

Below is the hardware and driver summary. It's an Acer with Intel i5. I have 2 identical monitors. Both worked when I did the initial install of Ubuntu (dual boot with Windows). Both show the splash screen with animations, but as soon it gets to the desktop GUI only one screen is live. If I leave the second screen powered the other display flickers every few seconds. Using Settings you can see the OS detects the display briefly then disconnects. If I switch ports the same thing happens in reverse. When I boot into Windows both displays wsork normally.

I don't know what to do. I have tried repair, refreshing the apt repository. The USB image I just made and booted from has the same problem. I am a Linux newb, so give simple steps please. Telling me what to do without an example is no help at all. I did try booting with Xorg. Both screens live at login, the same result at GUI.

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: i915 v: kernel ports:
    active: HDMI-A-2 off: HDMI-A-1 empty: none bus-ID: 0000:00:02.0
    chip-ID: 8086:4692
  Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.21.1.4 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: vesa unloaded: fbdev,modesetting
    gpu: i915 display-ID: 0
  Monitor-1: HDMI-A-2 model: 24N1 res: 1920x1080 dpi: 92
    diag: 604mm (23.8")
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 730 (ADL-S GT1)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
```

Comment: I can only assume the answer is give up on Ubuntu and try a different OS.